# Spring Security Recommended Design To Request User Login to Different User With Different Role

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, security

I have the following use case and need recommendations on the proper implementation.  To be clear can this be done through configuration or do I need to implement new code?

**Business Use Case**

The business wants to allow a user to login via social media sites and access some of their pages.  But in order to access pages that deal with $$ the user must login via the applications local account.

**Technical Use Case**

Allow users to login via Facebook or other provider and provide role USER_PARTIAL_RIGHTS

If user accesses a page with role USER_FULL_RIGHTS prompt the user to login to an account that is a local JDBC stored account.

This authentication must also ensure that the page is protected by USER_FULL_RIGHTS role and not other roles.

I am using grail spring security plugin, but I am expecting to have to customize the plugin.

So what are recommendations for doing this?  A couple of ideas that I have are:

**Technical Ideas**

- custom spring access denied handler
- custom access denied controller instead of the stock jsp page

Comment: What is your question then (it's a Q/A site after all)?

Comment: @Xaerxess I add more to my question: can I configure this or do I have to implement new code.  Will a custom access denied handler work be or should I implement a custom access denied handler?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail but Spring Security OAuth might be what you're looking for. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/

Comment: So oauth will let me authenticate with various sources, but I do not see how it would help me with the different roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up implementing is a controller that looks at the role and redirects the user to the correct landing page.  Kinda messy, but it works.

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> inferred = SpringSecurityUtils.findInferredAuthorities(SpringSecurityUtils.getPrincipalAuthorities());

if(ifAnyGranted('ROLE_FOO', inferred)) {
  redirect(controller: 'foo',action: 'home')
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question, here is my suggestion.
For login via Facebook use Spring Social. [Here](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social/) is the documentation. The implementations are straightforward.  Write a custom signin method and set the authorities for partial rights, something like this:

```
    public void signin(String userId) {
    authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            //set your partial rights authority
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, authorities));   
}
```

And do a method level security implementation using the @secured annotation to access the page that needs full rights. Something like this

```
 @Secured("USER_FULL_RIGHTS ")
 yourMethod(){
 //code
 }
```

This would prompt for a login where can use authentication from applications local account.

Comment: So it is my understanding that this would not prompt the user for a login, but would send them a 403 or to an error page (depending on the configuration) see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#access-denied-handler ... I need to prompt the user for a login only if it is appropriate :(

Comment: Oh yea, sorry for that. One way to handle 403 it would be to override handle() method in [AccessDeniedHandlerImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.html) but i don't have a sample code for it. :(